# Computational Chemistry: calculation of sterical effects

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

Is there a way to calculate sterical forces between atoms/groups of atoms (preferably with free and open source tools)? I have heard that this is possible within the framework of NBO. I am using ORCA, nwchem and Gaussian09 mostly. Sterics are obviously one of the most important aspects of organic chemistry but still I could find close to no resources on the computational chemistry aspects of it. It would be nice to have a way of quantifying sterics and also visualizing it somehow.

Does anyone have some experience on that?

Comment: Just ran a cursory search and ran into http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3555760 on calculations of the anomeric effect. Not sure if the reference points at what you had in mind.

Comment: What about using Bader's QTAIM? There is [some](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp073801y) literature in that regard.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you're searching for non-covalent interactions; if so, here's the usual Wikipedia link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-covalent_interactions

But more importantly here's the paper describing the software, http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja100936w and here's Prof Rzepa's blog with 'non-covalent interaction' searched, http://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?s=non-covalent+interaction

That's the start, post again when you want to know how to implement it.

Comment: Useful links thanks for that. : ) But I don't really mean the broader non-covalent interactions I mean steric repulsion. And I have seen some papers describing "new algorithms" how to accomplish that but I am searching for an _already existing software_.

Comment: It looks like a software package called NBO 5.9 will do it.  Again from Prof Rzepa's blog, http://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=1887#comment-4793 ... hopefully this time.

Comment: NBO 5.9 is propietary though (and probably also very expensive), I know there is the open source alternative JANLA but I could not find information about if this includes sterics as well. Anybody used JANLA?

Comment: The software is JANPA - I did not use it so far.